# No dump after AJAX Request in Laravel

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, request

I tried out Ajax for the first time now in my life in Laravel.
I want to send a value from a selection-list via AJAX-Request to my TableSelectionController, because I dont want to reload the website.
The problem is, that there is no dump coming, after I typed `dd($request)`. I want to see the data, that is coming in for further editing.

But the Jquery-Script is returning "success".

So I think the request is not reaching the controller. I tried for serveral hours finding a solution but I cant get it. Maybe someone here knows whats going on.

```
tableselection.blade.php: 

<body>
<form id="search-form">
    <div id="search-form-filters" data-filters-count="1">
        <div class="filter">
            <select id="select-options">
                <option value="customer">Kunden</option>
                <option value="contact_person">Ansprechpartner</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Suchen</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('#search-form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        table = $('#select-options').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/search-form',
            type: "POST",
            data:{
                table: table,
            },
            success:function(response){
                if (response) {
                    console.log("success");
                    $("#search-form")[0].reset();
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("failure");
            }

        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

```
web.php

<?php

Route::get('/',function () {return view('tableselection');});

Route::post('/search-form', [TableSelectionController::class,'gatherData']);

?>
```

```
TableSelectionController:

    public function gatherData(Request $request)
    {
        dd(json_encode($request));
      
    }
```

bump after 24 hrs.

Comment: You can follow your request (XHR, ...) with the "development tools" of your browser (firefox)

Comment: *"So I think the request is not reaching the controller."* - Open the browser's developer tools (F12), switch to the network tab, potentially check "preserve logs across requests" and then watch what's going on.

Comment: Use this useful and easy package to render your dump on console in order to not pollute your GUI and not loose msg. https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-dump-server

Comment: @Dri372 @Tomalak Thank you for the tip. After trying the tool out, I got this ```"{"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}"```
Pretty empty. :/ But shouldnt php print out an empty "Request" - Object anyways?

Comment: @Darky Does that mean the request went through and the server answered with `200 OK` and sent you this?

Comment: try dump or ($request)

Comment: @Tomalak Exactly this. I got a 200 and this was the preview. Headers contained formdata : table: customer.

Comment: How do you get these data? What's the return of dump($request)?

Comment: @Dri372 I dont get any dump. The website looks like before.